# How can I retrieve and store a value in a variable in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with these values:

```
<query>
    <club>First</club>
</query>
```

And an XSLT file where I want to retrieve the value from the XML. How can I retrieve and store the club value in a variable in XSLT? I've done something similar in XSL by storing variables like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="testVar">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable = 'hello'">
        <xsl:text>msg=hello</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>msg=bye</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But not with XPATH...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. You've stored values in a variable in XSL, but you want to know how to do it in XSLT? XSL is the same as XSLT, except for the XSL-FO vocabulary, which is irrelevant to this discussion. Are you asking how to declare a variable in an XPath expression (your last sentence, as opposed to the title and the middle paragraph), so that it's available for use later within the same XPath expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XPath, just use the `select=` attribute to address your item:

```
<xsl:variable name="givenClub" select="/query/club"/>
```

... or, if your current node is `query`, then:

```
<xsl:variable name="givenClub" select="club"/>
```

Comment: Hi the first one works fine but how do you know which node you are in?

Comment: By the context of where you are writing the instruction based on the last node matched and any context changes since then.